# The main differences between 特有 and 固有

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I cannot differentiate the meaning of 特有 and 固有. The following 2 sentences seem to be (roughly) identical in their meaning.

> A: 合気道は日本特有の武道である。
>
> B: 合気道は日本固有の武道である。

Both means:

> *Aikido is a martial art that is peculiar to Japan.*

## Question

What are the main differences between 特有 and 固有? Please give me some examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd translate like:

> A: 合気道は日本特有の武道である。
>   *Aikido is a martial art that is **characteristic** to Japan.*
>
> B: 合気道は日本固有の武道である。
>   *Aikido is a martial art that is **indigenous** to Japan.*

特有 means something X that belongs to Y has unique feature not commonly seen in similar things that belong to others than Y; thus we can translate it as *special* or *distinctive*.  固有, on the other hand, tells X belongs to Y by nature and never to others; thus the translation will be *proper* or *inherent*.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer of broccoli forest is perfectly correct.

I'll tell you the difference between the two words based on the 漢字｛かんじ｝*kanji*s used in 固有｛こゆう｝*koyuu* and 特有｛とくゆう｝*tokuyuu*.

> 固有 = 固 + 有, and 特有 = 特 + 有
>
> - 有 means 存在｛そんざい｝する or 保有｛ほゆう｝する which means "to exist" or "to have/possess".
> - 固 has many meanings, but in this case it means 元｛もと｝より *motoyori* which means "from the beginning/start".
> - 特 means そのものだけ特別｛とうべつ｝/特殊｛とくしゅ｝ which means "to be special only for it/the thing".

As a whole, 固有 means 元｛もと｝より存在｛そんざい｝する or 元｛もと｝より保有｛ほゆう｝する or "existing/having from the beginning", which means "inherent", on the other hand, 特有｛とくゆう｝ means そのものだけに特別｛とくべつ｝に存在｛そんざい｝する or "existing/having only for it", which means "characteristic".